# WooCommerce products multiple fields custom searching

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce

I would like to enable search of multiple WooCommerce products, like in **the screenshot below**:
[image: **This screenshot**]

1st dropdown will list the **`{Manufacturer}`**:

- When user selects a brand from this dropdown the 2nd dropdown will list the related Models **`{ModelNo}`** of the Brand.
- When user selects the model from the 2nd dropdown, query will run and will display the results in the “search results page” as list.

Results page can be list or User will click on the product from the results page and then the product page will be displayed.